# What is the "Feedback" Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using Chrome version 30.0.1588.0 dev on Linux Mint 15 and I see this strange extension.
I cannot find it in `chrome://extensions`, but it appears on the *New Tab* page with other apps like YouTube, Store and Gmail.

[image: New Tab page screenshot with the suspicious Feedback icon]

Upon clicking it, it just closes the current tab. In its context menu, it has no settings or a removal option.

What is the purpose of this extension?

Comment: It's likely a feedback extension

Comment: @Ramhound feedback for what? what are data sent by this app? I want to remove this app because, I don't like to 'feedback' anything.

Comment: Feedback for the alpha version of update 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noted, you're using Chrome 30 from the *dev* channel. Contrary to the *stable* channel, *dev* isn't stable ;)

It's an icon for a in-development feature that isn't completely implemented yet, it was added in the last update (build 1588). Such things just pop out from time to time in *dev*. I guess it will be just a shortcut to a feedback page, just as other icons out there; nothing to worry about.

As far as I know, the only automatic feedback feature is the one you can enable when downloading Chrome. Not sure if those two are linked in any way.

Comment: thanks, it is quite annoying that I returned to chromium.

Comment: You can temporarily switch to the *beta* channel, I believe it has less surprises like this one. To downgrade to beta you'll have to uninstall Chrome first, otherwise it won't downgrade until next beta update.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a standard extension installed with Chrome. It is likely added in by the Linux Mint team. You may be able to find the website associated with it by going to Tools -> Extensions and seeing the vendor.

It's very strange that its only functionality is to close the current tab. It may be broken. The intended purpose is probably to allow you to send feedback to the Linux Mint team about Mint or Chrome on Linux Mint.

Look in about:plugins to see if it is a native plugin. It may not be a proper Chrome Extension (JavaScript).

You can also remove an app by following the instructions from [Google](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1053346?hl=en) -- this would apply if it is behaving like a normal "app", and is not some kind of a native plugin.

Comment: it is not listed on Tools->Extensions(`chrome://extensions`)